# Скорость передачи данных в RabbitMQ.

Tags: rabbitmq

Здравствуйте. Решил изучить новую технологию для построениях масштабируемых приложений.
Выбор пал на MQ технологию и её реализацию RabbitMQ. Начала с теста скорости.
2 приложения: Отправщик и Получатель. Отрпавщик в бесконечном цикле формирует сообщения определённого размера и отправляет их в очередь. Получатель постоянно монитторя очередь принимает сообщения и инкрементирует счётчик количества принятых сообщений, каждую секунду выводя количество принятых за эту секунду сообщений.

И что оказалось. Если передавать по килобайту успевает отправиться и получиться 12 000 сообщений если передавать по мегабайту то всего 12. Отсюда делаю вывод что пропускная способность RabbitMQ Servera всего 12 мегабайт в секунду?

Честно говоря не верится. Возможно есть какие-то настройки сервера? 
Народ кто работал с данной технологией откликнитесь.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А отправщик, получатель и RabbitMQ работают на одной машине или это дело по сети бегает?

Comment: На одной машине.

Comment: просто 12мб очень похоже на 100мбитную сеть.

А какую скорость ожидаете?

Comment: @Алекандр, тут много зависит от конфигурации машины/окружения, и просто так сказать, реальный это предел или какие-то ограничения среды, не получится. Если можете скинуть код, я попробую у себя погонять, заодно с rabbitmq наконец познакомлюсь.

@KoVadim, nice catch!